# Minimal database for ASP.NET MVC 3 user management / membership

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I am new to ASP.NET MVC 3 and am dealing with database inherited by me from Visual Studio master. There are lots of stored procedures and user roles like `aspnet_Membership_BasicAccess`, `aspnet_Membership_FullAccess` etc.

Do I really need all this?

I can remember other MVC solutions, like Ruby on Rails's Devise authentication plugin: it needs only one-two tables and only one database access role - and it is still pretty secure.

What is the minimal database structure to support ASP.NET MVC 3 user management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is Yes, you need all this, because the Membership system relies on all those sprocs and roles.

The longer answer is, are you going to be using membership?  If not, then no.  If you're going to be using membership, are you going to be using SqlMembershipProvider?  If so, then yes, you need those.  If you're going to use the Universal providers instead, then you will need a different set tables and supporting configurations.

So without knowing *anything* about what you're doing, all we can say is, if you don't understand why it's there, then don't mess with it.

I fail to understand why you mention Rails, as it's a totally different toolset and framework.  It's like complaining that your motorcycle needs gas and oil when your bicycle doesn't (not that i'm saying Rails is less powerful, just saying it's different).

**ASP.NET MVC doesn't *do* user management by itself**, but it does include some templates that rely on the default ASP.NET Membership system.  In Visual Studio 2010 this uses SqlMembershipProvider by default, but in Visual Studio 2012 it uses the Universal Providers by default for MVC3, and SimpleMembership by default in MVC4.

ASP.NET MVC doesn't know or care how you do your user management, it's not part of the framework.  It delegates it via Authorization filters, which by default merely look at the ASP.NET IIdentity and IPrincipal.

If you're going to do user management, you need to decide on how you're going to do that.  Either roll it yourself (custom membership provider, custom IIdentity and IPrincpal provider, etc...), or use an existing membership provider (there are many, and Microsoft has at least a half dozen different ones).  Or you can just choose to go with the defaults, in which case it's pretty much already in a pretty bare minimum situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you derive from the membership provider and create your own custom provider, you can implement a very minimal set of properties.

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    private string _appName;
    private bool _EnablePasswordReset;
    private bool _EnablePasswordRetrieval;
    private int _MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts;
    private int _MinRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters;
    private int _MinRequiredPasswordLength;
    private int _PasswordAttemptWindow;
    private MembershipPasswordFormat _PasswordFormat;
    private string _PasswordStrengthRegularExpression;
    private bool _RequiresQuestionAndAnswer;
    private bool _RequiresUniqueEmail;

    public override string ApplicationName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._appName;
        }
        set
        {
            this._appName = value;
        }
    }

    public override bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username, string password, string newPasswordQuestion, string newPasswordAnswer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool DeleteUser(string username, bool deleteAllRelatedData)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool EnablePasswordReset
    {
        get { return this._EnablePasswordReset; }
    }

    public override bool EnablePasswordRetrieval
    {
        get { return this._EnablePasswordRetrieval; }
    }

    public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByEmail(string emailToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int GetNumberOfUsersOnline()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string GetPassword(string username, string answer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string GetUserNameByEmail(string email)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts
    {
        get { return this._MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts; }
    }

    public override int MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
    {
        get { return this._MinRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters; }
    }

    public override int MinRequiredPasswordLength
    {
        get { return this._MinRequiredPasswordLength; }
    }

    public override int PasswordAttemptWindow
    {
        get { return this._PasswordAttemptWindow; }
    }

    public override MembershipPasswordFormat PasswordFormat
    {
        get { return this._PasswordFormat; }
    }

    public override string PasswordStrengthRegularExpression
    {
        get { return this._PasswordStrengthRegularExpression; }
    }

    public override bool RequiresQuestionAndAnswer
    {
        get { return this._RequiresQuestionAndAnswer; }
    }

    public override bool RequiresUniqueEmail
    {
        get { return this._RequiresUniqueEmail; }
    }

    public override string ResetPassword(string username, string answer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool UnlockUser(string userName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void UpdateUser(MembershipUser user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        //put your db code here.
    }
}
```

Then you need to modify your web.config file to call your new provider

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="CustomMembershipProvider"
         type="MembershipExample.Providers.CustomMembershipProvider, MembershipExample"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

You can also implement your own custom roleprovider if you have any specific role-based security

Comment: I always discourage custom membership providers unless you absolutely need them.  It's not easy to implement username and password management securely, and it's really easy to do it insecurely without even realizing it.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment, but he asked.

Answer (score 1):

The one you are referring is a legacy Membership Provider in which tables are prefix with `aspnet`.

[New ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) doesn't use Store Procedure anymore. Instead, it uses Entity Framework and it is a bit cleaner.

If you want minimum database structure, you might want to look at [SimpleMembership](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)